# Find the longest sequence of "1"s.?

Tags: javascript

Given an array:

```
['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

1). I want to find the longest sequence of "1"s in an array
2). Arrange the sequence of "1"s and "0"s in ascending order in a new array while alternating the "1"s and "0"s.

I am not getting the logic using javascript. Can anyone help me. This is one of my interview question.

Comment: I don't understand the second part. *"Arranging the sequence of ones and zeroes in ascending order"* and *"alternating the ones and zeroes"* seem like competing/contradictory requirements to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does your code satisfy requirement 1? Requirement two doesn't make sense.

Comment: If you follow requirement two and sort the array, you will have all zeros and then all ones. Alternating them will create a sequence of 0 and 1 and this will keep repeating and thus, it will violate the longest sequence rule (then longest sequence of 1 will be of length 1)

Comment: it looks like the reuslt should be a new array with a new order by the longest arrays of the same value in alternating values an descending order of the length.

Comment: If this is an inteview question, are you allowed to post it here?

Comment: i was attend a interview on last month. i dont have idea about that question.  so i was posted that question for my knowledge and upcoming interviews it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You could separate the array into arrays of same values and sort this array by the length.

For getting an array with alternating arrays of values, you could use an array (or object) for keeping the next index of the sorted result array.

```js
const 
    data = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
    temp = data
        .reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
            if (v !== a[i - 1]) r.push([]);
            r[r.length - 1].push(v);
            return r;
        }, [])
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length),
    indices = [1, 0],
    result = [];

for (const array of temp) {
    result[indices[array[0]]] = array;
    indices[array[0]] += 2;
}

result.forEach(a => console.log(a.join('')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```